# How to generate automatically the name of output parameters in a python script tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, geoprocessing

I have some Python script tools in ArcGIS for Desktop.

I need to reproduce what all geoprocessing tools do when the first input parameter is introduced: autogenerate a workspace and basename for the outputs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how a workspace is being auto-generated with a GP tool?

Comment: there isn't enough detail in your Q for us to help. Perhaps include a sample of your script, reduced to it's simplest possible form (sometimes pseudo code can be clearer than the real thing). Also What GP tool do you see creating a workspace automatically? (most ask for a pre-existing workspace). ...and finally a tip: add the GP tool to a model, then export as python script. That will show you how the tool does it. (And if that works, come back and answer your own question so others can benefit from your research)

Comment: Sorry, What I need is the output workspace and basename to appear in the tool dialog box, when the user select a first input dataset. It's a behavior of all geoprocessing tools in arcgis.

Comment: I think I have to adapt de validation process for that. Or something about the schema, but I dont control pretty well these terms, nor how to work with them.

Comment: Well, it should be something with the validation process, because it happens before the tool runs, when the user is interacting with the tooldialog box...

Comment: Are you looking for this: [Setting script tool parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000n000000)? You can set defaults for the input parameters, but I am not aware of how to auto-populate them with the current workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [arcpy.Describe()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Describe/03q30000008q000000/) and/or the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) Python module. For  example:

```
import arcpy, os
input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_workspace = arcpy.Describe(input).path # the file path, or geodatabase for geodatabase datasets
suffix = 1
output_name = arcpy.Describe(input).baseName + "_" + suffix # the file base name + a suffix
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input, os.path.join(output_workspace, output_name))
```

You can also check for the existence of the output if you want to make sure it doesn't already exist, increment the suffix if it does, etc.

**EDIT:** Based on the example above, if you want to have this `output_name` value returned in the tool's interface as asked in your comment, you should modify the validation code:

```
def updateParameters(self):
  if self.params[0].value:
      output_workspace = arcpy.Describe(self.params[0]).path 
      suffix = 1
      output_name = arcpy.Describe(self.params[0]).baseName + "_" + suffix
      self.params[1].value = os.path.join(output_workspace, output_name)

  return
```

And your script should look like this:

```
 input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
 output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
 arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input, output)
```

Don't forget to import all necessary modules in both codes.

Refer to [Customizing script tool behavior](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000t000000), this is where the code comes from and there are other examples for other use cases.

Comment: Hi, but how to show the "output_name" variable in the dialog tool box???

Comment: You can do that by modifying the validation code of your script tool. See [Understanding validation in script tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000002v000000) and  [Customizing script tool behavior](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000t000000)

Comment: I had already checked these pages, but I don't find how to modify the UpdateParameter method in validation. I'm looking for some codes, without success.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help GISGe. As my input data is a Raster Layer, the Describe gives an error ("Describe input value is not a valid type"). I have tried to introduce de raster dataset by browsing, but got the same error. The function recommended by help would be: `workspace = os.path.dirname(self.params[0].value.value)` . But also get an error.

Comment: Try with `os.path.dirname(self.params[0].value)`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have found thanks to GISGe's hint is modifying only the updateParameter() method in validationtool class, adding this code.

```
if self.params[0].value:
    self.params[4].value = "output"
```

This will generate a string with the default workspace with basename, "output". I dont have to modify the python script at all.

Thanks to all!!!